# Creating a link to folder which does NOT allow recipients to edit documents within the folder

Tags: permissions, links

I want to send someone a link to a folder but **not** allow them to edit **any** of the documents within that folder. When I create a link to a folder and deselect 'allow editing' they're still able to edit each of the individual documents. What should I be doing instead?

Answer (score 0):

Emily -  What permission level is assigned to the user?  Read would allow them to open and download.  For Office documents, the View Only permission level combined with configuring the library to open documents in the browser by default would allow them to view only - no download.  It sounds like you'll need to create unique permissions (aka break permissions inheritance) on the folder and assign the user the necessary permission level.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into what permission levels the group has.